# How to create a button with a list of different menus in c#?

Tags: c#

How do I add multiple operations in a button click, like when I press the button in my windows form it would show me a list of processes and when I click on that process name in that list then only the code assigned to that process will get executed?
For better understanding, say I have a simple windows form app with two text boxes and a button. When I put values on both the textboxes and click on the button, then it would show me 4 options, namely `ADD`, `SUBSTRACT`, `DIV` and `MULTIPLY` and when I click on one of them, the code added to that process only executes.

Answer (score -1):

Should the button become a list or is it a separate list and button? For option 2 you can create a invisible list. That will be visible when button is clicked. For option 1 see the answer of NineBerry.

Comment: how do I create a invisible list?

Comment: Via the visible property